# Sending child's process ID to parent through pipe

Tags: c, cygwin, pipe, fork

I am tasked with writing a C program that creates 10 child processes in a loop, each of which would send its ID to the parent through a common pipe, the parent would print each child's ID separately and then print the sum of all children IDs.

My attempt is as follows :

```
    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include  <sys/types.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main(void){

     int sum=0; 
      int id=0;
      int descriptors[2];
     int children[10];
     pipe(descriptors);
     printf("Dad's pid : %d \n",getpid());

     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     int x=fork();

    if(x== (pid_t) 0){
    close(descriptors[0]);
    id=getpid();
      children[i]=getpid();
      printf("Process id %d \n",getpid());
      write(descriptors[1],&id,sizeof(id));
       exit( 0 );
     }

     else if(x> (pid_t) 0){
     close(descriptors[1]);
     read(descriptors[0],&id,sizeof(id));
     children[i]=id;
     sum=sum+id;

     }

      }

      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      printf("child process %d's ID : %d from parent : %d \n",i,children[i],getpid());
        }
      printf("The total sum of children IDs is : %d \n", sum);

     return 0;
       }
```

After a few tries I decided to add that printf process id line to try to see where the fault's occurring, this is the resulting output:

```
     Dad's pid : 18240
     Process id 24100
     Process id 4900
     Process id 21924
     Process id 23168
     Process id 4820
     Process id 10568
     Process id 22152
     Process id 6100
     Process id 21868
     child process 0's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 1's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 2's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 3's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 4's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 5's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 6's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 7's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 8's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     child process 9's ID : 24100 from parent : 18240
     The total sum of children IDs is : 241000
     Process id 22824
```

This is obviously not the desired result. Why is the first child process's id getting duplicated for all process IDs? And why is there an extra parent process at the end giving me that process id line after printing the sum at the end?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The thing that jumps out at me is, the `close(descriptors[1])` is screwing up the environment passed to children 2 through N. You need to hold that open in the parent until you're done creating _all_ the children. There are probably more bugs.

Comment: I don't think you have an extra 'Process id'. I think there are 10 ? And you know that fork() in the parent returns the child id, so I don't understand why you want to derive and return that from the child process....

Comment: zwol's suggestion was the one I needed. Removing that line and adding it after the for loop has solved the problem 100%. 
Many thanks, zwol!

@Brian , my instructor wants to test my understanding of the pipe and fork function, I am already aware I can immediately print the child's ID but that's not the point. That extra process id line no longer shows up as well after trying zwol's suggestion.

Comment: Why would you want to send child id to parent through pipe ? when fork returns to parent process the pid of the created process. Just save it in a list or an array if you know the number of processes you wish to create...

Comment: @TonyTannous  please read my reply to Brian.